# TinyMCE failing to load CSS file from cloud

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm seeing a pink box with

Failed to load content css: https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/skins/lightgray/content.min.css

popup when tinymce.init runs. My app is written in Meteor with Bootstrap3. The TinyMCE editor is inside a bootstrap modal. The editor window displays but I can't set focus by clicking in it and the contents that I'm setting with .setContent don't appear (but the "Powered by TinyMCE" appears in the lower right so I know that the editor was rendered by TinyMCE and not just a textarea). I'm loading TinyMCE from the cloud like this:

```
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=myKey"></script>
```

My init code looks like this:

```
tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea',
     auto_focus: 'editorId',
     height: 400,
     menubar: false,
     toolbar: false,
     statusbar: false,
     resize: false,
     plugins: 'paste',
     paste_as_text: true,
});
```

This only happens in Firefox (54.0.1 32-bit), everything works fine in current versions of Chrome, Opera, and Edge.

I'm not the only one having this problem. See [here](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3763) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1371910). Firefox claims it is a TinyMCE issue, everyone else seems to blame Firefox.

Anyone have any suggestions of what to try?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Hosting TinyMCE locally rather than loading from the cloud works. Two downsides; I have to rebuild and republish my app to get updates, and this increases the size of the bundle that has to be pushed to the client browser from my server. But it allows me to continue on with TinyMCE.